# Writing to a file with mode "w" versus "a" - I can't get "w" to work properly

Tags: python

Let me start out by saying I am very new to Python.  I'm taking a Udemy bootcamp, so I am not by any means condoning my solution as the best solution, but for the life of me, I cannot figure out why, when I write to the output files, I have to use mode "a" instead of "w".  If I use "w", it only writes the last line of the starting_letter.txt.

invited_names.txt is a .txt file attached to the project with the following records.  There is no new line `\n` after the last name in the file:

```
Aang
Zuko
Appa
Katara
Sokka
Momo
Uncle Iroh
Toph
```

The starting_letter.txt file is also attached to my project.

```
Dear [name],

You are invited to my birthday this Saturday.

Hope you can make it!

Joel
```

The function of the program is to replace [name] from the first record in the starting_letter.txt file with a name from the invited_names.txt file and create an output file for each name in invited_names.txt. I would prefer to use mode "w" so the files get overlaid each time the file runs because mode "a" obviously will append to an existing file if it already exists. I compared my code to the instructor's solution, and I can't see why hers works with "w", but mine doesn't.

```
invited_names = open("./Input/Names/invited_names.txt")
invited_names_list = invited_names.readlines()

for i in range(len(invited_names_list)):
    invited_names_list[i] = invited_names_list[i].strip()

starting_letter = open("./Input/Letters/starting_letter.txt")
starting_letter_list = starting_letter.readlines()

for name in invited_names_list:
    for line in starting_letter_list:
        new_line = line.replace("[name]", name)
        with open(f"./Output/ReadyToSend/letter_for_{name}.txt", mode="a") as file:
            file.write(new_line)
```

Comment: You are opening file each time for the lines to be written. That is why the previous lines are being overwritten and you see only the last line. Move only the `with open(....` line after the outer loop and before the inner loop

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. :)  I tried that, but it still creates files with only the last line of the starting_letter.txt being in the output files. I see what the instructor did that is different, and I could certainly mimic it.  I was just trying to get my solution to work.  The extra for loop is the issue.  My solution just doesn't work. I was close, but no cigar!

Comment: can you also show the code where you have tried opening the file before the inner loop? That should work

Comment: Sorry for the terrible formatting.  I am trying to figure out why it's not working.  I do have the code working now, and I see the error I was making.

I had to fix this by removing the second for loop.  It was completely unnecessary.  I also changed the readlines() to read().  This way I pulled in the whole starting_letter.txt.

starting_letter_list = starting_letter.read()

for name in invited_names_list:
    new_line = starting_letter_list.replace("[name]", name)
    with open(f"./Output/ReadyToSend/letter_for_{name}.txt", mode="w") as file:
        file.write(new_line)

Answer (score 1):

Updated functional code, please note the line of code that opens the file. In `w` mode it opens a new file and it should be outside of the for loop. In your code it opens a new file inside the second for loop and gets overwritten in each iteration of second for loop.

```
invited_names = open("tmp_data/invited.txt")
invited_names_list = invited_names.readlines()

for i in range(len(invited_names_list)):
    invited_names_list[i] = invited_names_list[i].strip()

starting_letter = open("tmp_data/starting_letter.txt")
starting_letter_list = starting_letter.readlines()

for name in invited_names_list:
    with open(f"tmp_data/letter_for_{name}.txt", mode="w") as file:
        for line in starting_letter_list:
            new_line = line.replace("[name]", name)
            file.write(new_line)
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
with open(f"./Output/ReadyToSend/letter_for_{name}.txt", mode="a") as file:
```

with

```
with open(f"./Output/ReadyToSend/letter_for_{name}.txt", mode="w") as file:
```

Answer (score 0):

My code was simply not good. :D

I had an unnecessary `readlines()` call for the starting_letter.txt. I read too much into the instructors hints and overused that method.

I had to remove the second `for` loop and also change the opening method for starting_letter.txt to be a `read()` instead of a `readlines()`. This allowed me to pull in the whole starting_letter.txt and do one edit on it, rather than parsing through every line to do it. I'm a newbie, and it's showing!

```
starting_letter_list = starting_letter.readlines()
```

should have been

```
starting_letter_list = starting_letter.read()
```